# HTML5 tags not working in Dreamweaver 5.5

Tags: html, tags

I want to use the new [HTML5 new input types](http://programmingbulls.com/html5-new-features) such as color,date picker etc for [HTML5 Tutorial](http://programmingbulls.com/html-5-introduction) in my site.

I am using Dreamweaver 5.5 to work to work on these new tags but they are not working.I

searched on google so i got to know that i need to tag

libraries or something like that.But i don't know how to use them.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>`
<html>
<form action="html-date" method="get">
Date:<input type="date" name="date" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

But when i see the output i get a simple text field instead of date picker.
If someone has used HTML5 in dreamweaver then help me.

Comment: Can anyone in this whole site solve my problem..I have to use it

Comment: I m not allowed to ask questions.. Why is that so??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have typed the code correctly, then it depends whether your browser supports HTML5 as to whether or not they will display correctly when you view your HTML page in browser. What browser are you using?

AFAIK, currently, the only browser to support date picking is Opera, your code seems correct, it's simply lack of compatibility with whatever browser you're using to view it. :)

Comment: @vipul you won't get far with such attitude. People are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to insert any tag with Dreamweaver, just switch to the code view and add them there.

Comment: i have done that..See my code and u'll understand the problem i m facing

Comment: It all looks correct, although the date tag isn't very well supported, take a look at this for more info http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-date

Comment: I need to know y are the tags not workin in dreamweaver when it supports HTML5.Everything is correct  in the code can u help me or not??

Answer (score 0):

If it does not even work in a browser why would you want dreamweaver to display it?

Dreamweaver only tries to display what a browser would display and in this case it does the right thing: it displays what anyone with firefox or internet explorer would see (probably 95%+ of your visitors)

To test what it would look like in another browser of your choice (chrome for example) you should load your page from disk or upload it to your webhost and try it in that browser.
That's the only way to see how that specific browser will display your page.

Comment: actually it is working in opera but i want it to work in Dreamweaver.